# Is there a Microsoft program for students to get Office free (or cheap)?

Tags: microsoft-office

As a computer science student, I've become accustomed to having free access to some Microsoft software through a number of programs like MSDNAA and Dreamspark. However, I have not found any such program offering a free or cheaper version of Microsoft Office, at least for my University. Is there something I'm missing or do I have to purchase the Home and Student Edition at 150$? Microsoft Word would be enough, but Excel would be nice.

I know about OpenOffice.org and I'm using it, but I would like to have some of Office's features. I've tried the free web Office 2010 stuff, but it does not support equations, which I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The student discount for the ultimate/full edition of Office is usually called "The Big Steal", but it probably won't be on for a few weeks until the University year starts, I cannot find the link.

However, [here is a link](http://www.microsoft.com/student/office/en-gb/default.aspx) to the Academic version of Office 2010 Professional at a heavily reduced rate - [The link](http://www.microsoft.com/student/office/en-gb/default.aspx) is for England, but you can choose your region near the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good discount. I'm still hoping for an even cheaper opportunity but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @Trillian - This edition is better than home and student, but remember that also home and student gives you three licences, so you may be able to spread the cost with others.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the deal they offer once school starts is significantly better.

Comment: Last year's deal was $60 for 2007, but the page is currently only redirecting to the main MS Pro Accademic for $80 offer.  I've included the link here in case it changes to offer the better price again later in the year.   www.theultimatesteal.com

Answer (score 1):

The Home and Student edition often goes on sale, hitting $60 briefly last year.  Currently, Dell has the retail version for $99, which comes with media and is licensed for installation on up to 3 computers.

Be careful not to buy the download only ("license card") version, since that one is licensed for just a single install.  That version typically saves just $10-20 over the 3-seat version.

Answer (score 0):

Also check with your campus software reseller.  At times individual campuses have site licenses which are much lower than even those prices, basically costing you media prices.

Answer (score 0):

What about 2010 Started edition? Its free and add support but It might do everything you need to if you can deal with the ads.
It might be OEM only, but I'm sure you could find it somewhere.